# Wordpress website redirects to localhost when accessed via IP address

Tags: wordpress, apache

I am hosting a Wordpress website from my home connection. I want to work on the website "via localhost" but at the same time have it accessible by others on the "actual internet". I am able to access my website via my phone by typing my home's (public) IP address into the browser, but my phone's browser redirects to "localhost". After a bit of Googling I suspect this is because my Wordpress/Site Address are still set to "localhost". I don't want to change the Wordpress/Site address to my public IP. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You just want to self host,  look into port forwarding for self hosting

Comment: You should replace site_url, home_url from localhost to "your IP address" like this: http://223.235.247.8/wordpress  from your database -> wp_options table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.